# Commands or shortcuts to put a selected region between parentheses or brackets in auctex

Tags: latex, auctex, region

If some region is selected region, then applying a command (such as the commands which insert an environment) provided by auctex results in putting the region in the corresponding environment.

Is these a similar auctex command which puts the selected region between `(` and `)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(LaTeX-insert-left-brace ARG)

Insert typed left brace ARG times and possibly a correspondig right brace.
Automatic right brace insertion is done only if no prefix ARG is given and
‘LaTeX-electric-left-right-brace’ is non-nil.
Normally bound to keys (, { and [.

Answer (score 1):

[smartparens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens) package has this behaviour by default for (, {, [ and ".

Additionally it is possible to add other chars:

```
  ;; wrap selection with a symbols
  (sp-pair "*" "*" :actions '(wrap))
  (sp-pair "_" "_" :actions '(wrap))
  (sp-pair "=" "=" :actions '(wrap))
  (sp-pair "+" "+" :actions '(wrap))
  (sp-pair "/" "/" :actions '(wrap))
  (sp-pair "$" "$" :actions '(wrap))
  (sp-pair "-" "-" :actions '(wrap))
  (sp-pair "«" "»" :actions '(wrap))
  (sp-pair "“" "”" :actions '(wrap))
  (sp-pair "´" "´" :actions '(wrap))
  (sp-pair "`" "`" :actions '(wrap))
  (sp-pair "'" "'" :actions '(wrap))
```